# TypeError: cats.map is not a function and Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cats.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, react-redux, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a simple Web API in ASP .NET Core and want to consume it using reactjs. When I write the dummy data in the react component, everything works fine. But as I fetch the data from my Web API it shows this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cats.map is not a function

I have enabled CORS and I can see the data using `console.log(data)`.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

export class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cats: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshList();
  }

  refreshList() {
    fetch("http://localhost:54962/api/Category/GetAllCategories")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ cats: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { cats } = this.state;

    return (
      <Table className="mt-4" striped border hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Category Id</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Parent Id</th>
            <th>Posts</th>
            <th>With SubCategory</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {cats.map(cat => (
            <tr key={cat.CategoryId}>
              <td>{cat.Id}</td>
              <td>{cat.Remarks}</td>
              <td>{cat.Name}</td>
              <td>{cat.Description}</td>
              <td>{cat.Image}</td>
              <td>{cat.ParentId}</td>
              <td>{cat.AddPosts}</td>
              <td>{cat.WithSubCatagory}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is what the data looks like in Postman:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the data that you're logging or rather what `cats` is when the component is rendered!?

Comment: @TobiasTengler this is the screenshot from postman. Thanks in adv

Comment: @TobiasTengler I would like to connect with you on LinkedIn..Can you please share your linkedin name because I could not find you there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a LinkedIn :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your Postman Screenshot. The data you're getting is an object with a `"Result"` property, which contains your array of cats.

In your component you store the whole object that is wrapped around your `"Result"` (or cats so to speak) into your `cats` state variable. Since `this.state.cats` is now an object and not an array, you can no longer call `map` on it, which leads to your error.

What you probably intended to do, was to only store the value of the `"Result"` property into your `cats` state variable:

```
fetch("http://localhost:54962/api/Category/GetAllCategories")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ cats: data.Result });
    });
```

Comment: oh..I got it.now its working. Thank you so much @tobias

Comment: Glad I could help you out! Could you please accept it as the answer, so others know that this issue is resolved?

Comment: Yes sure..I have voted it up. how can I accept it as answer?

Comment: Below the up- and downvote buttons there is a check-mark, you need to click.